# semaphore barriers exercise os three easy pieces

Tags: c, pthreads

I am reading the book OS three easy pieces, In the semaphore chapter I am going through barrier.c question.

Below is the code that needs to be completed for the desired output:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sched.h>

// If done correctly, each child should print their "before" message
// before either prints their "after" message. Test by adding sleep(1)
// calls in various locations.

// You likely need two semaphores to do this correctly, and some
// other integers to track things.

typedef struct __barrier_t {
    // add semaphores and other information here
} barrier_t;


// the single barrier we are using for this program
barrier_t b;

void barrier_init(barrier_t *b, int num_threads) {
    // initialization code goes here
}

void barrier(barrier_t *b) {
    // barrier code goes here
}

//
// XXX: don't change below here (just run it!)
//
typedef struct __tinfo_t {
    int thread_id;
} tinfo_t;

void *child(void *arg) {
    tinfo_t *t = (tinfo_t *) arg;
    printf("child %d: before\n", t->thread_id);
    barrier(&b);
    printf("child %d: after\n", t->thread_id);
    return NULL;
}


// run with a single argument indicating the number of 
// threads you wish to create (1 or more)
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    assert(argc == 2);
    int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    assert(num_threads > 0);

    pthread_t p[num_threads];
    tinfo_t t[num_threads];

    printf("parent: begin\n");
    barrier_init(&b, num_threads);
    
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    t[i].thread_id = i;
    Pthread_create(&p[i], NULL, child, &t[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) 
    Pthread_join(p[i], NULL);

    printf("parent: end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I have add the code and its giving the desired output but I am not sure In the questiing hint is to use 2 semaphore but I have used only one to accomplish the task
Below is my code:

```
typedef struct __barrier_t {
    // add semaphores and other information here
    //sem_t s;
    sem_t lock;
    int n_threads;
} barrier_t;


// the single barrier we are using for this program
barrier_t b;

void barrier_init(barrier_t *b, int num_threads) {
    // initialization code goes here
    //sem_init(&b->s, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&b->lock, 0, 1);
    b->n_threads = num_threads;
}

void barrier(barrier_t *b) {
    // barrier code goes here
    sem_wait(&b->lock);
    b->n_threads--;
    sem_post(&b->lock);

    while(b->n_threads >= 1) {
        //pthread_yield();      // causes the calling thread to relinquish the CPU.
        sched_yield();      // force the running thread to relinquish the processor
    }
}
```

I just wanted to know is i am in right direction or I am missing something, Thanks.

Complete code

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sched.h>

// If done correctly, each child should print their "before" message
// before either prints their "after" message. Test by adding sleep(1)
// calls in various locations.

// You likely need two semaphores to do this correctly, and some
// other integers to track things.

typedef struct __barrier_t {
    // add semaphores and other information here
    //sem_t s;
    sem_t lock;
    int n_threads;
} barrier_t;


// the single barrier we are using for this program
barrier_t b;

void barrier_init(barrier_t *b, int num_threads) {
    // initialization code goes here
    //sem_init(&b->s, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&b->lock, 0, 1);
    b->n_threads = num_threads;
}

void barrier(barrier_t *b) {
    // barrier code goes here
    sem_wait(&b->lock);
    b->n_threads--;
    sem_post(&b->lock);

    while(b->n_threads >= 1) {
        //pthread_yield();      // causes the calling thread to relinquish the CPU.
        sched_yield();      // force the running thread to relinquish the processor
    }
}

//
// XXX: don't change below here (just run it!)
//
typedef struct __tinfo_t {
    int thread_id;
} tinfo_t;

void *child(void *arg) {
    tinfo_t *t = (tinfo_t *) arg;
    printf("child %d: before\n", t->thread_id);
    barrier(&b);
    printf("child %d: after\n", t->thread_id);
    return NULL;
}


// run with a single argument indicating the number of 
// threads you wish to create (1 or more)
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    assert(argc == 2);
    int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    assert(num_threads > 0);

    pthread_t p[num_threads];
    tinfo_t t[num_threads];

    printf("parent: begin\n");
    barrier_init(&b, num_threads);
    
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    t[i].thread_id = i;
    pthread_create(&p[i], NULL, child, &t[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) 
    pthread_join(p[i], NULL);

    printf("parent: end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile:
$ gcc -g -Wall -l pthread barrier.c

output:

```
 $ ./a.out 5
parent: begin
child 0: before
child 1: before
child 2: before
child 3: before
child 4: before
child 4: after
child 0: after
child 2: after
child 3: after
child 1: after
parent: end
```

Comment: As code uses `#include <unistd.h>`, I'd expect question to be tagged Linux, Unix  or the like.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very inefficient barrier. You are using the semaphore as a mutex that guards access to `n_threads`. After decreasing `n_threads` with the "mutex" held, you go into a loop where you check the value of `n_threads` without a lock. That's already very dangerous. Furthermore, `sched_yield()` is just a hint to the operating system that it *should* schedule another thread, however the operating system can decide not to do that, or if there are more cores than threads, there will not be any thread to schedule, so it will effectively be a busy loop that is using CPU power needlessly.

The solution you posted is a possible way to do it that avoids unsafe access to `n_threads` and avoids busy-waiting.

Comment: I forgot POSIX semaphores don't allow initialization with negative values, otherwise you could make a barrier with just the semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.

I have to use two semaphores: one to use as lock and other to wait for the `n_thread` to become zero, when `n_thread` is zero `sem_post` will wake up the thread, causing chain of `sem_post` to wake up each other.

Here is my solution:

```
typedef struct __barrier_t {
    // add semaphores and other information here
    sem_t s;     // for barrier
    sem_t lock;  // act as lock while decrementing n_threads
    int n_threads;
} barrier_t;


// the single barrier we are using for this program
barrier_t b;

void barrier_init(barrier_t *b, int num_threads) {
    // initialization code goes here
    sem_init(&b->s, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&b->lock, 0, 1);
    b->n_threads = num_threads;
}

void barrier(barrier_t *b) {
    // barrier code goes here
    sem_wait(&b->lock);
    b->n_threads--;
    sem_post(&b->lock);

    sem_wait(&b->lock);
    if (b->n_threads == 0)      // check if n_thread is zero then wake up waiting thread
        sem_post(&b->s);       // wake up waiting thread
    sem_post(&b->lock);

    sem_wait(&b->s);
    sem_post(&b->s);           // wake up waiting thread

}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. While you can post an answer to your own question, if you are looking for additional code review on your updated code it would be better to post a follow up question with a link back to your original question.